# In MySQL is it best practice to wrap LOCK TABLES calls in a try catch?

Tags: php, mysql, try-catch

When executing a "LOCK TABLES" is it wise to wrap the call in a try/catch to make sure the table gets unlocked in case of an exception?

Answer (score 2):

In general it's a good idea to use `try { } catch` for operations that require undoing a previous operation in case of any errors; it's not limited to just database statements.

That said, when using databases, it's advisable to use a more granular locking mechanism such as the one that comes with transactional databases such as InnoDB. You would still use `try { } catch`, but in this manner:

```
// start a new transaction
$db->beginTransaction();
try {
    // do stuff
    // make the changes permament
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // roll back any changes you've made
    $db->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

The exact behaviour of conflict resolution is defined by the transaction isolation level, which can be changed to suit your needs.

Comment: In my case I need to safely do a get and write to a table while ensuring that concurrent writes do not happen during that time. Do transactions give this same behaviour or is Lock Tables better to ensure this?

Comment: @JordanC There's no easy answer to that; sometimes it's bad design and sometimes you simply can't escape a full table lock. But I find that often row level locking works pretty well.